# Session Time Out when connecting web app to console application vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I am new to StackOverflow, please help

I have two servers, one is the development server, and the other is SIT, when I am connecting my web application with console application with a command:

```
 Dim P As New Process                   

 P.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XYZ\XYZ.exe"                   
 P.StartInfo.Arguments = Batch_ID
 P.Start()
```

When I am connecting in SIT environment, the console application worked until the task completes, while when I connect in Dev Server, the console application closed after some time without completing whole task.

I have checked all the setting life application pool time, server ideal-time out it's all the same.

Please help me with the solution as I am not able to get any alternative for this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that this qualifies as "Oracle" question,,,

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open `.exe` file using asp.net ?

To make the configurations easier, we will keep the `exe` location in the `appsettings` in web.config so that it can be configured easily.

`<appSettings>
   <add key="EXELOC" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XYZ\"/>
 </appSettings>`

**Calling an exe from ASP.Net**

The service account in which the ASP.Net is running should have proper access to exe location and should have all the access to the resources the exe is trying to access; else code will not start the exe.

At times, it is required to specify additional settings to have a control on the exe running the server.  The ProcessStartInfo class in System. Diagnostics namespace can help us in these scenarios to achieve our goal. Refer the code below,

```
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string locn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EXELOC"];
    Process myProcess = new Process();
    try
    {
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = locn + "XYZ.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.Start();                  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```